# ImportError: No module named 'pygame' on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pygame

I'm susing python3 preinstalled with my Ubuntu 18.04 and installed pygame with command `sudo apt-get install python-pygame`. But `import pygame` doesn't work. How can I fix that?

Comment: did you do `pip install pygame` ?

Comment: No i only did `apt-get install python-pygame`. Is the other one necessary?

Comment: You need `pip` (or `conda`) to install any external library to Python. See this - https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted#Pygame%20Installation

Comment: Or I think it installed in pygame in Python 2. Maybe try importing in Python 2 terminal? To install explicitly in Python3, do `pip3 install pygame`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three ways to check this:

**1**. Using `apt-cache` to search and `apt-get` to install :

```
apt-cache search pygame
```

Result:

```
python-pygame - SDL bindings for games development in Python
```

Then install:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pygame
```

**2**. Using `pip`:

```
pip install Pygame
```

**3**. Manual installation:

- Download the source from [Pypi](https://pypi.org/project/Pygame/#files);
- Extract the `.tar.gz` file, and install using:

  `python setup.py install`

*obs: check the python version you want to install, if you use Python3, use:*

```
pip3 install Pygame
```

Answer (score 0):

For python3, you can install Pygame using this command:

```
pip3 install Pygame
```